# WP7.1 System.NotSupportedException: "LaunchForTest is not supported"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone application using Visual Studio 2012 and the WP8 SDK with the `Target Windows Phone OS Version` set to `Windows Phone OS 7.1`.
Mode is Debug and for testing I am using the SDK shipped "Emulator 7.8" (same results with "Emulator 7.1" and the WP8 emulator or even on my WP7.8 device).

My code is as follows:

```
#if DEBUG
      public void Test()
      {
         if (ScheduledActionService.Find(ReminderName) != null) {
            try {
               ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(ReminderName,
                                                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
         } else {
            MessageBox.Show("No scheduled notification has been installed");
         }
      }
#endif
```

After invoking this method via a button I get the following debug output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
Microsoft.Phone.dll LaunchForTest is not supported
System.NotSupportedException: LaunchForTest is not supported
at Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(String name, TimeSpan delay)
at RingReminder.Control.RingAgent.Test()
```

I am at a loss here, since the [ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method states: 
`Windows Phone OS | Supported in: 8.0, 7.1`.

Searching for this problem on SO or Google didn't bring up anything either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReminderName` sounds like it's of type [Reminder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The `Reminder` class derives from the [ScheduledNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.schedulednotification%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class, not the [ScheduledTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledtask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class. The `NotSupportedException` is thrown in the `LaunchForTest` method when the supplied object is not of a `ScheduledTask` object. That's why you're likely getting the exception, because the `Reminder` object is not of type `ScheduledTask`.

Comment: Arg, that's it. It'd have taken me a long time to find that one. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it's not the most obvious cause :)